# Passing Dropdown Value To URL in Django

Tags: python, django

I am rendering a dropdown which displays a list of integers. This is the only field in the form/view.  Once that form is submitted, the integer selected should be passed to the URL of the next view which is rendered on submission of the previous form.

I am getting a 404 when I attempt this.

Here is what I am currently trying:

forms.py

```
#this is the dropdown field
class ManifestDropDown(forms.Form):
    reference = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Orders.objects.values_list('reference', flat=True).distinct(),
    empty_label=None)
```

views.py

```
#this is the view where the dropdown is submitted
def manifest_references(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManifestDropDown(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
            form.save()
            return render('manifest', reference_id=reference_id)

    query_results = Orders.objects.all()
    reference_list = ManifestDropDown()

    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'reference_list': reference_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'manifest_references.html', context)


#this is the view where the value should be displayed in the url
def manifest(request, reference_id):
    form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == "POST":
        ....



    data = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=reference_id)
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={

         'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id),

         })
    total_cases = Manifests.objects.filter(reference__reference=reference_id).aggregate(Sum('cases'))

    context = {
    'reference_id': reference_id,
    'form': form,
    'data': data,
    'total_cases': total_cases['cases__sum'],

     }

    return render(request, 'manifest_readonly.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
#url which displays the manifest view above
url(r'^manifest/(?P<reference_id>\d+)/$', manifest, name='manifest'),

url(r'^references_manifests', manifest_references, name='references_manifests'),
```

manifest_references.html

```
<div class="container">

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <form method="POST" action="references_manifests">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ reference_list }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Create Proforma</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: you have 2 solution. 1- write javascript code to generate url as you want with dropdown value. 2- change your view to get parameter as POST not from URL

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change the URL that you're actually submitting to, you would need to use JavaScript.

But an alternative is to submit back to the `manifest_references` view, then redirect from there to `manifest`. (Note, you should always be redirecting, not rendering, after a successful submission anyway. And no need to call `form.save()`, this isn't a modelform so there is nothing to save.)

```
def manifest_references(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManifestDropDown(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
            return redirect('manifest', reference_id=reference_id)
```

Comment: I tried the above and I am still getting a 404 error - is there possibly something wrong with the URL?

Comment: A 404 where? Show the full error, and also show your template; did you update the form action to point to manifest_references rather than manifest?

Comment: Oh oh I see - I had not update the form action.  I've added the template above and added the url for ```manifest_references``` view.  As you can see I have now updated that form action to point to the correct url.  I am no longer getting the 404 but when I submit the dropdown, the page simply refreshes and never redirects to the ```manifest``` view.

Comment: You should probably call form.save() before calling return redirect(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

- Call the manifest view directly.
- Redirect the user to the manifest page.

The first one should be done like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
        reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
        form.save()
        return manifest(request, reference_id)
```

The second one can be done like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
        reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manifest', reference_id = reference_id))
```

It doesn't really matter which one you do, although I would recomment redirecting the user to the correct page, because then a refresh will not resend the form the user has entered.

Comment: I tried this answer and I still am getting a 404.  Should everything be kept the same within both the ```manifest``` view and the url when using the example above?

Comment: I tried the second method here - where do I need to point the form action in the template I posted above? and do I need to make any amendment to the URL I posted above?